# Eclipse says PrintStream never closed even though it is closed

Tags: java, resource-leak, printstream

Should i close PrintStream only with try/catch/finally blocks or is there another way?

Or is this a bug in the IDE?

```
public void writeData(String fileDir) throws IOException{

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileDir);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ps.print(stringData[i]);
        ps.print("-");
        ps.print(doubleData[i]);
        ps.print("-");
        ps.print(intData[i]);
        ps.println();

        boolean control = ps.checkError();
        if(control) {
            throw new IOException("IO exception occurred!");
        }
    }

    ps.close();

    System.out.println("Data transfer completed!");

}
```

Comment: Use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). This code does not guarantee to close the stream.

Comment: Your code throws an `IOException` on at least one code path. Without a `try-finally` (or `try-with-resources`) you would leave the file handle behind `fos` open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the control variable is true, a IOException will throws, so, in this case, you never close your PrintStream.

You must close your Streams always in a try-finally block or, if you use java 1.7, in a try-with-resources.

In addition, you have forgotten to close the FileOutputStream too.

**try-finally**

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileDir);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);

    ...

} finally {
     fos.close();
     ps.close();
}
```

**try-with-resources**

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileDir); PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos)) {

    ....

}
```

Comment: Closing the `FileOutputStream` is not necessary here: The `PrintStream` takes ownership and closes the `FileOutputStream` when the `PrintStream` is closed. (Same applies to `Scanner`, which closes `System.in` if it was constructed using that - leading often to other bugs.)